# How to average slices of a 3D Matrix maintaining its shape

Tags: python, matrix, raster

I got this working code snippet:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

in_raster = np.random.randn(36, 3, 2151)
matrix = np.reshape(in_raster, [(np.shape(in_raster)[0] * np.shape(in_raster)[1]), np.shape(in_raster)[2]])
#  reshaping the matrix to prepare loop
out_raster = np.empty([np.shape(in_raster)[0]/3, np.shape(in_raster)[1]/3, np.shape(in_raster)[2]])
#  creating empty output matrix

i = 0
j = 0
while i <= len(in_raster)-9 or j < len(out_raster):
    if i % 9 == 0:
        avg_in_raster = np.nanmean(matrix[i:i+9, :], axis=0)
        out_raster[j] = avg_in_raster
    i += 9
    j += 1
out_raster = np.reshape(out_raster, [np.shape(out_raster)[0], np.shape(in_raster)[1]/3, np.shape(in_raster)[2]])

# plot example
low = 0
high = 50

for row in range(0, 3):
    for col in range(np.shape(in_raster)[1]):
        plt.plot(range(low,high), (in_raster[row, col, low:high]))
plt.plot(range(low,high), (out_raster[0,0,low:high]), 'k')
plt.show()
```

The program averages (aggregates) 3x3 slices of the input matrix (a raster image) and sets up a new one maintainig the dimensionality of the original matrix.

Now I got the feeling that there must be an easier way to achieve this.
Does somebody have an idea how to obtain the same result in a more pythonic way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no easier or quicker way to perform blockwise averaging. Your code might look big, but most of it is just preparation of arrays and resizing or plotting stuff. Your main function is a well-placed `while`-loop and the averaging itself you leave to `numpy` which is already a shortcut and should run quickly.

I don't see any reason to further shorten this, without losing readability.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make it look shorter and "more pythonic" but less readable, go for this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

in_raster = np.random.randn(36, 3, 2151)

size=3

matrix=np.array([in_raster[:,:,i].flatten() for i in np.arange(in_raster.shape[2])]).transpose()

out_raster2 = np.array([np.nanmean(matrix[i:i+size**2, :], axis=0) for i in np.arange(len(matrix)) if not i%size**2]).reshape(np.shape(in_raster)[0]/size, np.shape(in_raster)[1]/size, np.shape(in_raster)[2])

# plot example
low = 0
high = 50

for row in range(0, 3):
    for col in range(np.shape(in_raster)[1]):
        plt.plot(range(low,high), (in_raster[row, col, low:high]))
plt.plot(range(low,high), (out_raster2[0,0,low:high]), 'k')
plt.show()

#plt.plot((out_raster2-out_raster)[0,0,low:high]) # should be all 0s
#plt.show()
```

And you could make it a function/method with the attribute `size = 3` and quality checks (first and second dimension can be divided by size, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it by extending the shape in one direction and averaging it in that dimension. Like so:

```
out_raster1 = np.nanmean(in_raster.reshape(36*3//9, -1, 2151 ), axis=1).reshape(12, 1, -1)
```

To check for consistency,

```
>>> out_raster1-out_raster
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

   [[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

   [[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

   ...,
   [[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

   [[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

   [[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```